# How to implement connect-multiparty in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, sails.js

I've watched this example that uses Node.js (Express.js):

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/wiki/Node-example

My question is: How to create a service in Sails.js that can be used in Angular.js (View), that allows store files in a folder of the project, using connect-multiparty like the example?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a [controller](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/controllers) method in Sails
2. Bind it to a route in [`routes.js`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes)
3. Use `connect-multiparty` at top of your controller method (OR use it as a middleware in [`config/http.js`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/middleware))

Comment: can you show some code regarding this so that i can understand more?

Comment: Hi, it has been long. I'm not actively working on Sails.js/node.js anymore. Won't be able to provide sample code.